# How to write benchmark test in Golang for an cmd tool?

Tags: go, benchmarking

When I say cmd tool, I mean a tool program like:

```
var (
    m           = flag.String("m", "GET", "")
    headers     = flag.String("h", "", "")
    body        = flag.String("d", "", "")
    contentType = flag.String("T", "text/html", "")
    ......
)

func main() {
    // Using args above, create complex logics
}
```

I cannot just call main() in my Benchmark().

Is there any way to do this?

Or must I rewrite a function with args for Benchmark() to call?

Comment: No, there isn't. And it would  be a bad idea. If you have an actual function you can execute 1000times you can measure its runtime. For an executable you would include all the overhead of program startup. Maybe just delegate actual work to main2 and benchmark that.

Comment: @Volker I have seen many tools that just write args paring work and main logics in main(). It seems that I can only reconstruct it.

Comment: You've seen that a lot because that is the smart way to do it, specifically because it allows you to test/benchmark/reuse the functionality, separate from the application startup in `main`.

Answer (score 4):

It's a good practice to keep your `main()` as short as possible and delegate all the actual work to a function/method, which makes it testable and benchmark'able if you wish. It may look something along the lines of

```golang
// main.go
// go run main.go -h "Content-Type: application/json" -h "X-Request-ID: 12345" -d "Hello"
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

type headers map[string]string

func (h headers) String() string {
    hdr := make([]string, 0)
    for k, v := range map[string]string(h) {
        hdr = append(hdr, fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s", k, v))
    }
    return strings.Join(hdr, ",")
}
func (h headers) Set(value string) error {
    i := strings.Index(value, ":")
    if i < 1 {
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid header '%s'", value)
    }
    h[value[0:i]] = strings.TrimSpace(value[i+1:])
    return nil
}

var (
    method string
    hdrs   = make(headers)
    body   string
)

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&method, "m", "GET", "Method")
    flag.Var(hdrs, "h", "Headers")
    flag.StringVar(&body, "d", "", "Body")
    flag.Parse()
}

func main() {
    err := run(method, hdrs, strings.NewReader(body))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func run(method string, headers headers, body io.Reader) error {
    // implement your logic here
    return nil
}
```

and your benchmark

```golang
// main_test.go
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkRun1(b *testing.B) {
    hdrs := headers{"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "appication/json"}
    body := "Hello World"
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        run("GET", hdrs, strings.NewReader(body))
    }
}
```

Comment: What I'm testing is an opensource tool https://github.com/Pingze-github/hey, It's run() will be having 10+ arguments. So I don't wanna do what you say.

Comment: @pingze so use a `struct` with 10+ fields, or don't benchmark it. "I don't wanna" isn't a particularly good reason not to use the correct design.